# Angular testing - How to test an observable chain where two services are called?

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine

I am trying to test an observable chain where 2 services are called. I am trying to test if the both services are called exactly one time. Since both services return observables I use `mergeMap` to chain the calls as you can see bellow:

`app.component.ts`

```
public aliceInChain(): void {
    this.serviceA
      .doSomething()
      .pipe(
        mergeMap(() => {
          return this.serviceB.doSomethingElse();
        })
      )
      .subscribe(r => {
        console.log(r);
      });
  }
```

In my spec file I have:

```
describe("AppComponent", () => {
  let fixture;
  let component;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    const serviceASpy = jasmine.createSpyObj("serviceA", {
      doSomething: of()
    });

    const serviceBSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj("serviceB", {
      doSomethingElse: of()
    });

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [FormsModule],
      declarations: [AppComponent],
      providers: [
        { provide: ServiceA, useValue: serviceASpy },
        { provide: ServiceB, useValue: serviceBSpy }
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });



  fit("should call serviceA and serviceB", done => {

    component.aliceInChain();
    expect(component.serviceA.doSomething).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);


  });
});
```

I can make sure that the first service was called but how can I test that the second was aswell? Is this possible being the method being tested void?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of testing if the services were called, I would test what happens in the `subscribe`.

```
describe("AppComponent", () => {
  let fixture;
  let component;
  let serviceASpy;
  let serviceBSpy;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    serviceASpy = jasmine.createSpyObj("serviceA", ['doSomething']);

    serviceBSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj("serviceB", ['doSomethingElse']);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [FormsModule],
      declarations: [AppComponent],
      providers: [
        { provide: ServiceA, useValue: serviceASpy },
        { provide: ServiceB, useValue: serviceBSpy }
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  fit("should call serviceA and serviceB", done => {
    serviceASpy.doSomething.and.returnValue(of('hello')); // assuming doSomething returns an Observable<string>;
    serviceBSpy.doSomethingElse.and.returnValue(of('hello world')); // assuming doSomething else returns an Observable<string>
    component.aliceInChain();
    // not sure if the next two lines will work
    expect(component.serviceA.doSomething).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(component.serviceB.doSomethingElse).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    // assert what should happen in the subscribe
    expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith('hello world');
    done();
  });
});
```

Comment: I must confess that I am a bit confused by your answer but that might me because I left some names that I was using locally in the spies. I have edited my question to remove those values so maybe you want to update your answer as well. Thank you

Comment: This has somewhat worked, I made a few changes. I didn't use 'done' since the test has no async callbacks. Also the part of the console doesn't work since no spy for it was created and that is not purpose of the test. The calls to the services now work and the only explanation that I can come up with is that we are defining the return of the spies inside the test itself instead of globally when creating the spy. Still not sure how the asyncchronousness of the component method is handled on the test. If anyone wants to add to the discussion it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Okay that's good, I am not a JavaScript expert but I wonder about how the asynchronous nature of the tests work as well. I think in a testing environment, when there is a `subscribe`, Angular gives it precedence and allows it to complete before it gives control back to the test. This is not the case for promises and that's why there is a `fixture.whenStable()`.

Comment: It's not really clear how observables subscriptions work angular's standard test environment (jasmine). Some subscriptions work as expected others don't, NGXS referes it here (https://www.ngxs.io/recipes/unit-testing). I also created an issue in jasmine github in order to try to understand how it works (https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/1804).